# Regexp matching everything except certain group

Tags: regex

I have regexp: `/[aA]\/[aA]/`,
 
This regexp catch "a/a", "a/A", "A/A", "A/a" 
I need to reverse this procedure and to catch everything except the above examples.
So i found in another answers , that i can use "Negative lookahead".
and try it but without success.
This is what i've try : `/(?!([aA]\/[aA]))/`

Expected results : 
"Some text contaning A/A" - Wrong 
"Some text that not contain the above" - Right

Comment: which lang you're running? An example along with expected output would be better.

Comment: I'm using Library , that allows me to add validation rules.
But rules can be used only to describe what is allowed, not what is restrict

Comment: No, I've plan to use some string , no matter what, but if contain some from the above 4 examples have to be catch as wrong. e.g. Everything except
"a/a", "a/A", "A/A", "A/a"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use an anchored negative look-ahead:

```
/^(?!.*a\/a).*$/ig
```

It will match any line that does not contain `a/a` (case-insensitively).

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/tV6gY1/1)

If you have multiline text, replace `.*` with `[\s\S]*`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that helps